# how to refer one .phtml in the other views in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

am new in Zend framework.

I have one .phtml file, includes menus section. i need to add that .phtml file in to the views i.e views/scripts/index.phtml page.

how can refer that

please advice

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `render` helper:

```
<?=$this->render('menu.phtml')?>
```

If you want to pass specific variables to the rendered script, use the `partial` helper:

```
<?=$this->partial('menu.phtml', array("varname" => "value"))?>
```

The menu.phtml file must be in the search path, which usually is the path to the current module's scripts directory ( view/scripts ). You can either place the menu.phtml file in this directory, or add a directory to the search path using the addScriptPath() method on the view object.

Comment: thanks for your reply. <?=$this->render('menu.phtml')?> throwing error when we deployed in centos. instead of <?=$this->render('menu.phtml')?> we can use <?php echo $this->render('menu.phtml'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $this->partial('path/file.phtml', 'ModuleName')
```